# Not able to see the actual output with "print" statement

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am running the code to see the output,but not getting as expected:

***part of code***

```
element=driver.find_element(:link, "Empid")
print element
element.click
```

***Output***

```
D:\Ruby script>ruby filedownload.rb
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x2483f70>
D:\Ruby script>
```

But i expected here the actual value of the `href`.Say `https://www.example.com`.

***EDIT***

```
element=driver.find_element(:link, "Suppliers")
print element.attr(:href)
element.click
```

***output:***

```
D:\Ruby script>ruby filedownload.rb
filedownload.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `attr' for #<Selenium::WebDrive
r::Element:0x25619a0> (NoMethodError)
D:\Ruby script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are displaying the `Selenium` instance.

try this:

`print element.attr(:href)`

=== UPDATE ===

seems it is a bit different from `Nokogiri` :)

try:

`print element.attribute(:href)`

Comment: is this mentioned in the document? can you give me the link of that? I also need to see other element values,with such a print.

Comment: But could you give me the document link,where you found that?